# How to grab a row from a html table if a cell equals my query?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, charts, datatable

Hello everyone I have a datatable where I need to grab the rows that have a value in the colum[x] if it equals my "Variable"

The scenario is a asp.net webapp using mvc5.

To initialize my html I get the values I need on it from a DataTable

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt_MyDataTable.Rows)
{
   string cust_id = dr["cust-id"].ToString();
   string name = dr["name"].ToString();
   string type = dr["type"].ToString();
   string number = dr["number"].ToString();
   string data = dr["data"].ToString();
   int qa = dr["qa"];
   int tty = dr["tty"];
}
```

How can I get all the rows that match "myValue" in the column[name] so I can get all the "qa" & "tty" values to make a total sum out of them and use them in this highchart as a category.

For example in my table I have the names "Turtles", "Tacos", "Lemons", "Peppers", "Worms".

How can I retrieve all Turtles "tty" and "qa" values, make a sum of their total and add Turtles as a category in the highcarts using "tty" as a a column total in the highchart??

Can this be done using javascript only or do I have to use c#?

```html
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

 
 
 <figure class="highcharts-figure">
                <div id="container"></div>
                <p class="highcharts-description">
                </p>
            </figure>
            <script>
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['category1', 'category2', 'category3', 'category4', 'category5']
                    },
                    labels: {
                        items: [{
                            html: 'Total data',
                            style: {
                                left: '50px',
                                top: '18px',
                                color: ( // theme
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                                ) || 'black'
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                series: [{
                    type: 'column',
                        name: 'Total data1',
                        data: [7, 2, 1, 3, 4]
                    }, {
                    type: 'column',
                        name: 'Total data2',
                        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
                    }, {
                    type: 'column',
                        name: 'Total data3',
                        data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
                    }, {
                    type: 'spline',
                        name: 'Average',
                        data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
                        marker: {
                        lineWidth: 2,
                            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                            fillColor: 'white'
                        }
                    }, {
                    type: 'pie',
                        name: '',
                        data: [{
                        name: 'Total data1',
                            y: 85,
                            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
                        }, {
                        name: 'Total data2',
                            y: 155,
                            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
                        }, {
                        name: 'Total data3',
                            y: 12,
                            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
                        }],
                        center: [100, 80],
                        size: 100,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                        }
                    }]
                });
            </script>
            <style>
                .highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
                    min-width: 310px;
                    max-width: 800px;
                    margin: 1em auto;
                }
                #container {
                    height: 400px;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table table {
                    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
                    margin: 10px auto;
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 500px;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table caption {
                    padding: 1em 0;
                    font-size: 1.2em;
                    color: #555;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table th {
                    font-weight: 600;
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
                    padding: 0.5em;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
                    background: #f8f8f8;
                }
                .highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
                    background: #f1f7ff;
                }
            </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

i amn't used to work with highcarts but clearly you can get the series in the table

```
 let chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container', {/*chart options*/});
let series = chart1? chart1.userOptions.series:[];
```

now series have table columns and graphs each object contain the type(ex column,pie) and data array which holds the values of columns.

Comment: I'm not following you up can you output an example? Can't fit your code in mine

Comment: when you create the chart by doing Highcharts.chart('container', {......}); it returns an object of the chart itself